# How to add to export default class extends Component - ({navigation})?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with adding the {navigation} parameter to the export default class extends Component, I need it for the FlatList

How can I add it here?

```
export default class ENews extends Component {

  render() {
  return (

      <View style={styles.main}>

        <StatusBar style='auto'/>

            <FlatList 
              data={this.state.data}
              onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
              refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
              initialNumToRender={4} 
              contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
              keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id} 
              renderItem={({item}) => (
              
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FullNews', item)}>  
                
              
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )} />

      </View>
  );
  
}}
```

Comment: Is you Enew screen mention in stack navigator or it's simple component

Comment: simple component

Comment: You stack screen look like 
< ComponentName {...this.props.navigation}-->here you pass you navigation>

in  your Component
const {navigation} =this.props--> this line add inside render

Comment: Can I have a detailed example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get navigation from props you can either deconstruct this.props and get navigation like this

```js
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

or you can directly use it like this

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('FullNews', item)
```

But I suggest using deconstructing props

```js
    export default class ENews extends Component {
    
      render() {

      const { navigation } = this.props;

      return (
    
          <View style={styles.main}>
    
            <StatusBar style='auto'/>
    
                <FlatList 
                  data={this.state.data}
                  onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
                  refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
                  initialNumToRender={4} 
                  contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
                  keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id} 
                  renderItem={({item}) => (
                  
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FullNews', item)}>  
                    
                  
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )} />
    
          </View>
      );
      
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent class

```
export default class ComponentName extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        ...other component
        <ENews {...this.props}></ENews>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

you Component

```
 export default class ENews extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props; // here you destructuring you props
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
          initialNumToRender={4}
          contentContainerStyle={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FullNews', item)}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

change as above in your code